# Google Firebase - how to delete Crash reports?

Tags: android, firebase, crash-reports, firebase-crash-reporting, firebase-console

Have I finally gone blind or is there not an obvious way to delete Firebase Crash reports through the Google Firebase web console? My Android app is successfully logging reports but now I have a flood of "development crashes" that are eating up a lot of my view in the console.  It makes it very difficult to find actual beta user crashes (especially since I also can't seem to filter the crashes by date/time). Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The best thing you can do for the long term is to create two different instances of the app, one for debug/dev and another for release, and make sure they have different package names.  This should allow you to view them each independently in the console.  You can configure this pretty easily in your build.gradle.

This topic was also [discussed in more detail](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/3k3ZPnexF4s) on our firebase-talk group, but from the perspective of Firebase Analytics.  Be sure to click through to get more details on how the gradle build works.

As far as actually deleting the issues that come up, there's not currently a way to do that, but we are looking into that for a future release.  We definitely hear everyone's feedback on that.

Comment: +1 interest! We're in private beta testing during initial development, so we still get a fair amount of crashes in release builds and it would be nice to remove or at least flag ones that have already been addressed.

Comment: @TravisChristian It's being worked on actively.  Stay tuned.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but now there is a way to disable `Crashlytics` when in debug mode.

In your app level `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
//...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled: true]
        }
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled: false]
        }
    }
}

//...
```

And in your `AndroidManifest.xml` inside `application` tag:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
    android:value="${crashlyticsEnabled}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It has the option to Close the issue in the GUI.
I have attached the screenshot for reference..
[image]

Comment: I tried to close the issue, but not correct solution for me , since if the same error is repeated again, Dashboard will now show it. I need to show new errors that was repeated even the error itself was closed in the past

Answer (score 0):

As Doug answered, it isn't possible at the moment.

My method is to use the filter - when in dev/debug, you roll the version forward one minor version, and when you release you, use another version.

This way you can restrict errors that you're dealing with to your current version, and not changing the package names, or having two code branches open.