# How to clear Firebase Crash reports?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting, firebase-console

I am using Firebase crash reporting service for android.
See [Add Firebase to your Android Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Can any one help me to clear crash report from Firebase console or any way to remove it by Firebase crash android API?

Comment: visit this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493079/google-firebase-how-to-delete-crash-reports

Comment: Yes. But I want to find way to remove  crash report by code also.

Comment: I think this is not possible

Answer (score 1):

There is unfortunately no Firebase Crashlytics API.

Whilst you can receive notifications of new issues via Slack, Jira, Email etc, there is no way to modify the issues themselves except via the web interface.

This can be verified by observing the [triggers available in Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/extend-with-cloud-functions):

- `onNew()`
- `onRegressed()`
- `onVelocityAlert()`